# Download an image file and replace existing image file

Tags: android

I am trying to download an image file and override and existing file if it exists.

But it doesn't replace the existing file.

```
public static String saveBitmap(String url, String fileName, Context context,
        boolean deleteExisting) {
    File cacheDir;
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir = context.getDir("images", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    else
        cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
    if (!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();

    File f = new File(cacheDir, fileName + ".png");
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    // Is the bitmap in our cache?
    if (f.exists()) {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getPath());
    }
    if (bitmap != null && !deleteExisting)
        return f.getPath();
    else {
        // Nope, have to download it
        try {
            InputStream input = new URL(url).openConnection().getInputStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(input));
            // save bitmap to cache for later
            writeFile(bitmap, f);
            return f.getPath();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve the issue? Are there any exceptions?

Comment: No exceptions the download works fine, but if I empty the folder just before downloading all the image files are becoming blank

Comment: OK, then describe the steps you've taken to fix the problem.

Comment: well first i have tried deleting all the files in the folder, and the images became blank when displaying them

Answer (score 5):

Go through following code for storing file

```
private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave, String fileName) {

File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DirName");

if (!direct.exists()) {
    File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/DirName/");
    wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
  }

    File file = new File(new File("/sdcard/DirName/"), fileName);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried permission, if not then add this permission in `manifest`

```
  uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```